# ssh clone failed in gitolite at a GCP compute engine

Tags: gitolite, google-cloud-platform

After install gitolite in a GCP compute engine and added a new ssh public key in `gitolite-admin/keydir/charley_rsa.pub` and add a new repo for `charley`:

`conf/gitolite.conf`:

```
repo test
    RW+     =   charley
```

Then: `git clone gitolite-admin` in GCP local console is ok.

When we do `git clone` in remote local pc, it shows 'DENIED by fallthru' error

```
git clone ssh://git@serverip/test
Cloning into 'test'...
FATAL: R any test charley_rsa DENIED by fallthru
(or you mis-spelled the reponame)
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

( clone `testing (@all)` in remote local pc is ok )

Answer (score 1):

finally, it's resolved after updating the public key filename

I used the id: charley in the conf file: gitolite.conf

```
repo test
    RW+     =   charley
```

after change the public ssh key filename
from "charley_rsa.pub" to "charley.pub"

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa git@serverip info
hello charley, this is git@serverip running gitolite3 v3.6.6-13-g8bde76d on git 1.8.3.1

 R W    gitolite-admin
 R W    test
 R W    testing
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you add new keys is by first cloning gitolite_admin repo, modifying it and pushing back: that triggers the recompilation of the `~/.gitolite/` configuration files.

If you do anything directly on the server, then follow "[administering gitolite directly on the server](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/odds-and-ends/#administering-gitolite-directly-on-the-server)"

You would need at least

```
gitolite compile; gitolite trigger POST_COMPILE
```

Comment: yes the new key is added into gitolite. it's done directly in GCP server, since I clone gitolite-admin and edit gitolite.conf in GCP server console.

Comment: @yaocl Yes so my answers stands: follow carefully http://gitolite.com/gitolite/odds-and-ends/#administering-gitolite-directly-on-the-server

Comment: I'm sure the gitolite installation process is ok because I had tested the installation in a local docker instance.

Comment: @yaocl you still need to follow http://gitolite.com/gitolite/odds-and-ends/#administering-gitolite-directly-on-the-server, and to a `gitolite compile; gitolite trigger POST_COMPILE`.

Comment: `    $ ls ~/.gitolite/keydir
    admin.pub  charley_rsa.pub
    $ more ~/.gitolite/conf/gitolite.conf
    repo gitolite-admin
        RW+     =   admin
        RW+     =   charley
    
    repo testing
        RW+     =   @all
    
    repo test
        RW+     =   charley

    $ gitolite compile; gitolite trigger POST_COMPILE
`
'git clone ssh://git@35.185.141.189/test' in remote local pc still failed

I think GCP manages ssh key in other way thats is different from a stand alone server

Comment: Then try the official way, and try cloning the admin repo first